# Compare Linux application file system between 2 AWS EC2 instances

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, snapshot

We have a Java based application running in Linux EC2 instances. We have different components running in different EC2 instances.

Every month we go for an AMI upgrade by creating new instances, deploying the code and killing the old instances. We are facing challenge in making sure that all components are deployed successfully in the instances.

Are there tools to get a snapshot of the application file system from old instance before AMI upgrade and compare it with the snapshot taken from new instance after code deployment?

If so that will make our work easier. We have a tool of 8 instances running the application.

Comment: What do you mean by AMI upgrade? OS upgrade (or) larger capacity upgrade? or anything else.

Comment: It is OS upgrade or applying OS patches released by AWS for the EC2 instances.

Comment: Isn't running yum update on existing instances enough? this is like regular system maintenance, for this I don't think you need to re-deploy everything.

Comment: This is a real time Healthcare ERA processing application and updating the existing instances will have some downtime to the application. So in order to avoid that downtime we are following this process.

Comment: I personally feel you should choose mechanisms like Blue/Green deployment to avoid down times. Still I feel if it is just OS updates, you can fairly do this without having any downtime by bringing servers one after other down. https://cloudnative.io/docs/blue-green-deployment/